# Code to force refresh (crtl+F5) flexdashboard created in R not using Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, flexdashboard

What code and where do I need to insert it to force refresh of a flexdashboard produced in R (the .html file)?

I have a flexdashboard published in my website and I update it every month. However, I noticed some users aren't getting the new versions.

Some suggests to [change the name of the external files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936654/12131069), which I frankly don't know how to do, and I don't want the file name to change with every update.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680246/how-to-trigger-a-data-refresh-in-shiny) seems to work, but only when using shiny.

[This other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6439351/12131069) seems ideal but is far too complex to understand.

And [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884654/button-that-refreshes-the-page-on-click) is ok, but I would rather avoid it.

Do I need to insert something in an external CSS file and put it in the markdown YAML?

Thanks!